# Show more than 200 images in one post

Tags: posts, images

I have gallery post and its have more than 200 pictures in single post.

So, when i open this post, Its take more than 2 min to open page, and the images not open fast.

What can do ?

Comment: Thought about using a [lazy load](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=lazy+load) plugin? Ofcourse is the use of thumbnails also a recommendation (as mentioned by performadigital). I have no idea what kind of site you have but loading many images/photo's can be a pain, if not done right. But maybe you give it a try and who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Having so many images on one page isn't recommended.

You should split the images into smaller galleries and across more than one page (or use pagination) to lower the page load speed for each page.

To split a single post in several pages (adding pagination) you can just add  using the text editor.

Alternatively ensure you're image sizes are not too large or use thumbnails of a small file size to link through to your larger images individually.

Comment: So, How can put pagination in single post ?

Comment: I've added the solution to my answer for you concerning <!--nextpage-->